# jQuery get parent Element and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I am trying to get the element  from the HTML below:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf">test2</td>
  <td>test22</td>
  <td>
     <button id="deleteButton" onclick="deleteHit(this);" type="button" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf" class="btn btn-danger btn-embossed">Delete Record</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery code I have tried:

```
$("td[data-uid='" + uid + "']").parent().prev().fadeOut('slow');
```

The **uid** has the number **408bd653-c1bf** value.

So I am not sure why its not finding the previous TR parent.

Comment: td is not a parent tr is..

Comment: Your code will likely hide the preceding row (sibling to the parent row of the` td` you selected). Did you mean to hide the row that is the parent of the `td` you selected?

Comment: @AAB OOps, thats what i meant. Updated the OP to reflect that.

Comment: Give a look at **closest** function: _https://api.jquery.com/closest/_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a class to each button if you want to have many of them, not an id.

Like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf">test2</td>
  <td>test22</td>
  <td>
     <button type="button" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf" class="btn btn-danger btn-embossed deleteButton">Delete Record</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then the JQuery:

```
$(".deleteButton").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    $(parent).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypzfrxua/)

EDIT:

If you want the previous `tr` to be deleted, try this:

```
$(".deleteButton").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr");
    $(parent).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypzfrxua/1/)

Comment: That's right, I haven't noticed it. @StealthRT, I've edited this for you. You should merge the classes into one attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no previous `td`. If your table looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr></tr>  <!--- This gets hidden -->
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf">test2</td>
    <td>test22</td>
    <td>
      <button id="deleteButton" onclick="deleteHit(this);" type="button" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf" class="btn btn-danger btn-embossed">Delete Record</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because:

1. `$("td[data-uid='" + uid + "']")` selects `<td class="sorting_1" data-uid="408bd653-c1bf">test2</td>`
2. `.parent()` selects `<tr role="row" class="odd">`
3. `.prev()` selects the previous element, which either is the previous `<tr>` or if there isn't a previous row is nothing at all.

If you want to fade out the current row (that the delete button is in) you would do this:

```
function deleteHit(el){
  $(el).closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Now there's a much nicer way of doing this. Change your `button` definition to have a class (since you'll have more of them and you're only allowed one id on the whole page):

```
<button data-uid="408bd653-c1bf" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-embossed js-delete">Delete Record</button>

<script>
  $(".js-delete").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut("slow", function(){
      // Remove the element from the DOM when the animation is done.
      $(this).remove(); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a selector to the parent method, something like this:

```
$("td[data-uid='" + uid + "']").parent("tr").prev().fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to hide parent `tr` element:

```
function deleteHit(el){
    $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Or to hide previous `tr` element:

```
function deleteHit(el){
    $(el).closest('tr').prev().fadeOut('slow');
}
```

**NOTE**, when using `onclick` attribute, you're passing `this` (clicked button) to the method. You should then add the button as argument (`el`) in your method, as shown above `deleteHit(el)`